# How do I reuse a POST request and overwrites its payload?

Tags: go

I have use case where a Go Client with a file-watcher listens to changes in a file and sends these changes to a Go server. If the Client can't reach the server during the `POST` requests with the payload of the file changes, the Client will keep trying every 3 seconds to send the request until `err := http.NewRequest()` dosen't return a non-nil `err`

But If the Client is currently trying every 3 seconds to send a `POST` request but at the same time a new change occurs to the file under file-watch, I want the current `POST` requests's payload to be overwritten by the new payload(new changes from the file)

How Do I archive this best?

**Client code for sending an HTTP requests**

```
func makeRequest(method string, body io.Reader) (*http.Response, error) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    request, err := http.NewRequest(.., .., ..)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error: Couldn't make a new Request:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: Couldn't execute %s request:%s", method, err)
    }
    return response, err
}
```

**The function that retries until *err !=nil***

```
func autoRetry(f func() error) {
    if err := backoff.Retry(f, getBackOff()); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error: Couldn't execute exponential backOff retries: ", err)
    }
}
```

`autoRetry()` is just a function which takes a function and uses [ExponentialBackOff](https://github.com/cenkalti/backoff) to calculate the amount of tries until `err !=nil`

**The call to the method doing the POST request with retries**

```
func postTodo() {
    autoRetry(func() error {
        r, err := makeRequest("POST", getFileData())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if r.StatusCode != 200 {
            return errors.New("Error:" + r.Status)
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `getFileData()` grabs a snapshot of the file and that the application is not breaching one of the request limits in the [transport](https://godoc.org/net/http#Tranport), then you are not going to do much better than the posted code.  If the application does bump into the transport request limits, then create an io.Reader implementation that calls `getFileData()` on first call to Read and delegate to the reader returned from `getFileData()`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Okay I'm glad to her that I already made an optimal solution. But wouldn't it be possible to just cancel the request and make a new one? Or is it bad pratice?

Comment: The `getFileData()` function should get a current snapshot of the file.  There will always be a window where the server processes a stale version of a file.  Canceling an inflight request might help reduce the size of the window, but may not be worth the trouble.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Alright. Thank you for the help